# How to define variable outside method that is present inside method?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I'm trying to create a method that allows me to query SQL in ruby without typing `results = client.query('code')` for every query. Heres my current method but it says that results are undefined in my puts statement. When I don't use my method it works normally.

```
require "mysql2" 
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:username => 'buck19j')


def sql(code)
   client = Mysql2::Client.new(:username => 'buck19j')
   results = client.query(code)
end

sql('SHOW DATABASES')
puts(results.to_a)
```

How to define variable outside method that is present inside method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the method *return* the value, not *assign* it:

```
def sql(code)
   client = Mysql2::Client.new(:username => 'buck19j')
   client.query(code)
end
```

Then assign a variable when you call the method:

```
results = sql('SHOW DATABASES')
puts(results.to_a)
```

Answer (score 2):

`results` doesn't "go out" the sql method, because is a local variable. An approach would be to define it as an instance variable, and you could use then as you do with `puts` (still unclear what's the whole context of this).

```
def sql(code) 
  client = Mysql2::Client.new(:username => 'buck19j')
  @results = client.query(code)
end

sql('SHOW DATABASES')
puts(@results.to_a)
```

Other way would be just leave the function returns the `client.query(code)` value:

```
def sql(code) 
  client = Mysql2::Client.new(:username => 'buck19j')
  client.query(code)
end

puts(sql('SHOW DATABASES').to_a)
```